# Axios request URL changing with proxy when port is over 5 digits

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, axios

I've got an issue with axios while proxying requests at the moment. the following code works fine:

```js
await axios.get('https://example.com/some/other/directory', {
  method: "GET",
  responseType: "arraybuffer",
  proxy: {
  host: 'hostname.tld',
  port: 9999,
  auth: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
  }
});
```

this sends a request to `https://hostname.tld:9999/https://example.com/some/other/directory`, which is expected behavior

if i change the port to `10001`, the request then goes to `https://hostname.tld:10001/some/other/directory`

i have no idea why. any ideas on how to fix this?